# npm Requires a peer but none was installed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, dependencies

I am getting the following warnings but i didn´t figure out how to update them.
I also have tried to install the dependencies needed but it does not work.

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-super-tabs@2.6.3 requires a peer of ionic-angular@^3.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-translate@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-translate@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Could you please help me?

Best regards.

Comment: Add your `package.json` to the question.

Comment: I have same issue. It was fired when I installed `ng-translate`:
`npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save`.

Comment: I too have just started getting the ajv-keywords@2.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none was installed. I suspect this was due to running ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage then npm install --save @ionic/storage - I believe if you redirect output of 'npm ls' to a file it will help you track this stuff down. Seems to be to do with webpack 3.4.1

Comment: I have no idea what's going on with webpack on my project.. If I run npm view webpack version it says 3.5.1. Yet if I look at node_modules/webpack/package.json it has version at bottom written as 3.4.1. The code looks nothing like the official one here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json - Some sort of ionic hacked fubared version! - required by "/@ionic/app-scripts" ( @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3 from ionic-info) - author "Tobias Koppers @sokra"

Comment: I ended up deleting my node_modules folder and doing npm install again.. Seemed to fix it for me

Comment: Do you have `ajv` installed?

Answer (score 8):

Mine was saying:
`ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Upon searching for Ajv, I realized that ajv 6.0.0 is a release candidate so I added `"ajv": "^6.0.1",` to the `dependencies` im my `package.json` file instead.
I ran `npm install`. Then I reran my installation script and it eliminated my errors.

Hopefully, it will work for everyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what the warning is they might not matter.  I would only be concerned if you are having issues with translate.  other than that impossible to diagnose without knowing installed component or package.json

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that you did install the dependencies. For me, I get a similar

```
npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

but I already have react-dom@^16. I believe it is because in your package.json you may have one dependency in devDependencies and the others in dependencies. Note differences in --save-dev and --save.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the library was not installed, so I Google "npm ajv", in the npm web page I when to the Install box and copy the content "npm i ajv", then I open Powershell on the root directory of my Angular project and run the command. This added the library to my project and solved the issue.